# How do I change the appearance of a citation for Literature Review?

Tags: biblatex, formatting, citing, thesis

I am writing my thesis/dissertation and am refining my literature review. The literature I have written about has been cited but the citations across the entire paper are numbers (Which is what I want). However, for the Literature Review, I want the citations to appear by name or something meaningful rather than just numbers as it could become a bit vague to follow which papers are making which points.
E.g.
 `[1] considers x, y and z with the intention...` but I want something like `*Paper name* considers x, y and z with the intention...`

Any advice or recommendations are much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: If you are really using `biblatex` as suggested by the tags, you can use `\citetitle` for the title and `\citeauthor` for the author (though I recommend you still cite the entry with `\cite` to obtain the normal citation number afterwards, so your readers can find the full bibliography entry quickly). If you are using a different citation/bibliography system equivalent commands may or may not exits. Please show us a short example document that demonstrates how you generate citations and the bibliography in your document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) for more specific help

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response. For the sake of literature review, wouldn't it be easier to keep track of the specific literature as you're reading it when the name of the paper is provided vs a number... Or are you saying I cite the author/title AND use \cite to get the number?

Comment: I don't know a lot about best practices in literature reviews and I don't know about common practices in your area of research, so I can't really give you any useful here. What I was trying to say (and where I could have been clearer, sorry) is that I would recommend that at some point when you discuss a paper you *also* (in addition to whatever else you may use to refer to the paper) mention the "normal citation label" (in your case the number as produced by `\cite`), so that people can easily find the relevant reference in the bibliography.